# Why is $\langle n| (\hat{a}+\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2|n\rangle=2n+1$ for the QM harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

Consider a one-dimensional quantum-mechanical simple harmonic oscillator of mass $m$ and potential energy $\frac{kx^2}{2}$. The energy levels of this system are $E_n=(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega $ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ where $\omega^2=k/m$. The system is in the state $|n\rangle$.

**Find the expectation of the potential energy $V$.**

My solution: $\langle V \rangle=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\langle x^2\rangle=\frac{1}{4}\hbar\omega\langle n| \hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}|n\rangle=\frac{1}{4}\hbar\omega(\langle n|\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}|n\rangle + \langle n|\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}|n\rangle)=\frac{1}{4}\hbar\omega(\langle Nn|n\rangle + \langle n|Nn\rangle)=\frac{1}{4}\hbar\omega\cdot 2 n$ since $N|n\rangle=n|n\rangle$ with $N:= \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$. However, the solution in the notes is as follows:

$\langle V \rangle=\frac{1}{4}\hbar\omega(\langle n|\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}|n\rangle + \langle n|\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}|n\rangle)=\frac{1}{4}\hbar\omega(2n+1)$.

---

To me it looks as though the official solution confuses the Hamiltonian with the operator $N$. Or have I made a mistake and if so, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\hat{N}=\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$ and

$$[\hat{a},\hat{a}^{\dagger}]=1 \implies \hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}=\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}+1=\hat{N}+1$$
You are confusing that $\hat{N}^{\dagger}=\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ but $\hat{N}^{\dagger}\neq\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ since $$\hat{N}^{\dagger}=(\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a})^{\dagger}=(\hat{a})^{\dagger}(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^{\dagger}=\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}=\hat{N}$$

Comment: Note that check-my-work questions are off-topic on PSE, so typically one shouldn't answer them unless there is a physics concept one can focus on within the answer rather than just correcting a calculation

Answer (score 1):

You either didn't apply the operator to the bra correctly, or didn't take its adjoint correctly.  Specifically, if we define
$B = a a^\dagger$, then $B^\dagger = (a^\dagger)^\dagger a^\dagger = a a^\dagger$ (by the general rule that $(PQ)^\dagger = Q^\dagger P^\dagger$.  Thus,
$$
\langle n | B = \langle B^\dagger n| = \langle (a a^\dagger) n| \neq \langle (a^\dagger a) n |.
$$

Comment: Hopefully this focuses sufficiently on the conceptual difficulties inherent in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression $\langle n | a a^{\dagger} | n \rangle = n$ is wrong. The easy way to see this is to note that $a a^{\dagger} = 1 + a^{\dagger} a$.

Comment: Note that check-my-work questions are off-topic on PSE, so typically one shouldn't answer them unless there is a physics concept one can focus on within the answer rather than just correcting a calculation.